# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I want to load my css's styles.

```
import '../assets/home/css/style.css'
```

I'm using `'style-loader', 'css-loader'` but I got this error message:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in
>   '/Users/sm_emamian/Desktop/react js/shadyab'  @
>   ./app/containers/Intro.js 23:0-39

my `webpack.config.js`:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: __dirname
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      }
    ],
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css']
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: what version of your webpack?

Comment: my webpack version is `webpack@4.1.1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`npm install style-loader --save-dev`

Also style-loader should be used with the 'loader', not 'use'.

Webpack config line:
 
`test: /\.css$/,
 loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'`

Ref: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader